# ReactJS, JSX and <script>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to ReactJS and have been trying to figure out the best approach to setting up the front end. I am trying to use a bootstrap template (https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html). I know JSX and HTML are different but are also very similar. When I try and use a snippet of HTML from the bootstrap template as JSX, the styling will appear correctly in the browser, but none of the buttons or graphs work. I imagine this happens because JSX is different from HTML and the rendered version in the browser does not respond to the browser JS. Is there any way around this? Do I have to rebuild all the functionality that comes with the template in a component?

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: Use `className` instead of `class` in JSX for assgining a css class to you elements.It's a common pitfall.